# Runtime Error "Unable to cast object of type X to Y"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Controller :**

```
[NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.No)]
public ActionResult TicketReply(Guid uniqueTicketId   )
{
    var ticketReplyModel = new BsTicketReplyModel();
    var bsTicket = _bsTicketService.GetBsTicketByUniqueTicketId(uniqueTicketId);
    ticketReplyModel.BsTicket = bsTicket.ToModel();

    ticketReplyModel.DisplayCaptcha = true;
    return View("BsTicketDetails", ticketReplyModel);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TicketReply(BsTicketReplyModel model)
{
          ....
    return View("BsTicketDetails", model);
}
```

**Route :**

```
routes.MapRoute("Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.TicketDetails", "HelpDesk/TicketReply/{uniqueTicketId}",
                new { controller = "BsHelpDesk", action = "TicketReply", uniqueTicketId = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.Controllers" });

            routes.MapRoute("Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.TicketReply", "HelpDesk/TicketReply/Submit",
                new { controller = "BsHelpDesk", action = "TicketReply"},
                new[] { "Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.Controllers" });
```

**Razor Cshtml :**

```
@using Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.Models
@using Nop.Web.Framework
@model BsTicketReplyModel
@using Nop.Core.Domain.Seo;
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;
@using Nop.Web.Framework.UI
@using Nop.Web.Framework.UI.Captcha

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "HelpDesk/TicketReply", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    ......
}
```

I am getting this error on runtime. I got a debugger point on **[HttpPost]** . But it is not getting hit. But on the meantime this error occurred. And Problem is Showing in Fluent Validation. What is the Problem?Thanks in Advance
**Unable to cast object of type 'Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.Models.BsTicketReplyModel' to type 'Nop.Plugin.BrainStation.HelpDesk.Models.BsTicketCreateModel'.**

[image]

Comment: The error message seems quite clear to me. It needs `BsTicketReplyModel`, but you're giving it `BsTicketCreateModel`.

Comment: The error message mentions a type called `BsTicketCreateModel`. Somewhere you're passing in an object of that type, instead of `BsTicketReplyModel`. The code you posted doesn't contain any `BsTicketCreateModel`s, so the source of the error is probably not in there.

Comment: Sorry I questioned just wrong. i just Edited my question ... @Widor

Comment: On which line are you getting this error?

Comment: Its showing on a "No Source" File. @DavidG

Comment: I didn't get it. Is it some kind of Fluent Validation problem? I commented all the validation from model. Still no Luck. Its simply just a form submission. What could go wrong